# How to customize the edit button with JHTML

Tags: php, joomla

In Joomla, at this page: /component/com_content/views/articles/tmpl/default.php

There is this code (about line 62):

```
<?php if ($canEdit) : ?>
   <li class="edit-icon">
      <?php echo JHtml::_('icon.edit', $this->item, $params); ?>
   </li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

It shown only the edit icon, i want add next to icon, a text "Edit page".

PS: The text must be inside  tag:
 Edit page

How to do this?